# If Rectangle doesn't Contains Mouse Position

Tags: windows, mouse-position

I have a Rectangle which I can touch with this command below.

```
if ((mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed )&&
        TextureRectangle.Contains((int)MousePos.X,(int)MousePos.Y))
{
    // Action;
}
```

But is there a Command like "Not Contains", so I wanna do something else if the user touch out of the "TextureRectangle" area?

When I click to the Rectangle that both actions starts. I really dont know where the problem is.

```
if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed){
    if(TextureRectangle.Contains((int)MousePos.X, (int)MousePos.Y)) {
        music1.Play();
    } 
    else{
        music2.Play(); 
    }
}
```

my problem is that music1 and music2 plays at same time if i click on the Rectangle, i want that when i click on the Rectangle that music1 plays only (here is the problem , both starts to play)and when i click out of the Rectangle should start only music2 to play ( this case is ok)

Comment: Can you not just put ! in front?

Comment: Hi, In front of Contains? Like That !Contains((.... ? I tried that but it didnt help me -.-

Comment: No.  In front of Texture

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to get a programming book / ebook and start reading it. This is basic computer logic stuff.

```
if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    if (TextureRectangle.Contains((int)MousePos.X, (int)MousePos.Y))
    {
        // inside
    }
    else
    {
        // outside
    }
}
```

OR

```
if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    if (!TextureRectangle.Contains((int)MousePos.X, (int)MousePos.Y))
    {
        // outside
    }
    else
    {
        // inside
    }
}
```

Comment: I really couldnt solve it, logicly when i click inside he should only do the inside acttion, but it makes both , inside and outside action starts at same moment.The Rectangle is a moving Rect by the way, i think my problem has nothing to do with that